# Unable to validate cryptogram via BP-Tools

Tags: emv

I have **VISA** test card, also I can see cryptogram data and all EMV-data in log-file. But if I calculate cryptogram via BP-Tools-Cryptographic Calculator (EMV->Application Cryptograms->VSDC) I does not see the same result - cryptogram from card not the same as cryptogram calculated in BP-Tools.

Incoming data from logs :

---

```
82       : 3C00
9F36     : 02CF
9F10     : 06010A03A02000
9F26     : 9DAE464A3FD4B929
```

Based on 9F10 - Cryptogram Version Number is 10. According this I use VSDC->CVN10 and fill correctly all tags values.

[image]

---

**QUESTION :** what value I need to put on "session key" field ?

I have KMC (printed on top of card), also I have IMKAC from HSM side. 
I tried to use this keys from UDK-tab, also tried put keys into "session key" field - but without success - cryptogram from card not equal that cryptogram from BP-Tools.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a part from EMV Book 2. The one inside the block is what you need to implement to key in the unique key for Visa CVN 10.

[image]

Comment: Also I found another option online - https://paymentcardtools.com/arqc-calculator     . Here they look to handle the UDK generation part too. IF AND ONLY IF TEST KEY , you can try that link too.

Comment: Anyone could point me, where to find BP-Tools, latest version?

Comment: Looks like their download page got unregistered. have you tried  paymentcardtools.com/arqc-calculator  ? it too has almost everything..